# SQlite calculate percentile by grouping rows based on name

Tags: query, sqlite3

could you suggest the approach to calculate the percentile by grouping rows in sqlite table.

ex table:

```
Name          Value
name1          2
name2          0
name2          1
name1          5
name3          2
name4          6
name3          1
name1          2
```

I need to group by Name and calculate the percentile for each group. please provide some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Specifically you'll need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).